# Why is a function not defined at certain points in my script when I am requiring the function at the top?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am making a game using Javascript. I use webpack to bundle my modules, so at the end of each Javascript file I use `module.exports`. Here is an example:

```
//spaceship.js
var Spaceship = function(options) {
  this.position = options.position
  this.name = options.name
}

module.exports = Spaceship


//game.js
var Spaceship = require("./spaceship");

var Game = function() {
  this.num_spaceships = 5;
  this.spaceships = [];
  // DEBUGGER 1
  this.add_spaceships();
}

Game.prototype.add_spaceships = function() {
  // DEBUGGER 2
  for(var i = 0; i < this.num_spaceships; i++) {
    this.spaceships.push(this.randomSpaceship
  }
}

Game.prototype.randomSpaceship = function() {
  //DEBUGGER 3
}
```

At each of the debugging points above, if I open Chrome dev tools and type in `Spaceship` I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Spaceship is not defined(…)`

If I change function `randomSpaceship` as follows:

```
Game.prototype.randomSpaceship = function() {
  //DEBUGGER 3
  var s = new Spaceship();
}
```

Then at DEBUGGER 3, `Spaceship` is now defined (if I open dev tools I get that Spaceship is a function).

Why does this happen? I imagined it could have something to do with variable hoisting perhaps, but I am declaring and assigning the variable Spaceship at the top of the file game.js.

Comment: Note that when using function expressions, the values aren't assigned until runtime. You may be inspecting the variables before that has occurred. Change the expressions to declarations, e.g. `function Spaceship (options){...}`, and you might get a different result.

Comment: @RobG, what do you mean? I just tried with function declarations and the variable is still unavailable for inspection if not directly referenced inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you don't use `Spaceship` variable inside `Game` and  `add_spaceships` functions where `DEBUGGER 1` and `DEBUGGER 2` debugging points are located and so Chrome doesn't capture this variable in closure. In `DEBUGGER 3` you use the variable and so it's captured in a closure and you can inspect it.

Comment: What an useless debugger, then.

Comment: Isn't Spaceship declared and assigned in a scope outside of Game and add_spaceships? It's like a global variable inside of the file game.js isn't it? Shouldn't it be in all closures in this file?

Comment: @evianpring, no, it's not global, webpack wraps your code in functions, check the built files

Comment: ok so does this topic have more to do with how webpack works than how JS works? Because from what I thought I knew of JS, if I declare and assign a variable at the top of the file, it should be both in scope and assigned for the remainder of the code in the file. Is this correct from a JS perspective?

Comment: _at the top of the file_ - if the file's content is executed as is then yes, what you define with `var` becomes global variables, but if it's wrapped inside a function, then the variables are defined within this wrapper function's scope.

Comment: _ok so does this topic have more to do with how webpack works than how JS works?_ - I think it has more to do with how Chrome allows you to inspect variables that are accessible through closure, but not used within the function