# Angularjs : Access scope of controller when the controller function is invoked from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller and  a directive. In the link function of the directive I invoke a controller function. When the controller function is invoked I want to access the scope of the controller inside the controller function. But I get $scope as undefined. How can I access the current scope. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9t294ox6/1/

I can access the scope using "this" keyword but $scope is undefined. Why does this happen?

This is my directive

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
     scope: { someCtrlFn: '&callbackFn' },
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         scope.someCtrlFn({arg1: 22});
     },
  }
});
```

my controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.ctrlFn = function(test) {
    //Want to access scope here
    debugger
    console.log(test);
  }
}
```

My HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div my-directive callback-fn="ctrlFn(arg1)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are already getting the value ; whatelse you need?

Comment: I want to access the keyword $scope. $scope comes as undefined in my ctrlFn. I get the scope using keyword this. But $scope is undefined. Why does this happen

Comment: put `console.log($scope);` and you'll see it's working fine

Comment: This is really weird. Try removing the console.log($scope) and stop  the debugger inside ctrlFn  and check the value of $scope on the console. It comes as undefined. But when I add the statement console.log($scope) $scope gets printed.

Comment: @ASR, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37059362/2545680)

Comment: Ah Got it! Thanks.